# How copy xml data to mysql in 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdo

I have xml values category and subcategory and i want to insert it in database. this code will be working every day on server checking xml file if there are some changes and if there are it will update mysql database.

is possible i want to make 2 tables connected with each other for example i have several subcategories with one category and i want to make one table with categories and second table with subcategories and number of id from first table

[image]

```
<?php

// URL is not real this is for example

$url = 'http://xml.com/category'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main_data;charset=utf8", 'root', '');
foreach ($xml -> m as $row){
    $cat = $row->category;
    $subCat = $row->sub_category;
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cat (category, sub_category) VALUES (:cat, :subCat)");
    $sql->bindValue('cat', $cat);
    $sql->bindValue('subCat', $subCat);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category>
    <m>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 1</sub_category>
    </m>

    <m>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 2</sub_category>
    </m>
    <m>
        <category>Cat 2</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 3</sub_category>
    </m>
</category>
```

Comment: so?  What is the problem?  Where does the code not work?  You stated what you want and some code.  What does it do that you do not like or expect?

Comment: this code inserts data from xml to one table

Comment: i need to separate category and subcategory tables but link category id to subcategory table CATEGORY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first insert the subcategory value in the subcategory table.  Just the query:

```
INSERT INTO subcat (sub_category) VALUES (:subCat)
```

This assumes that the subcat table is defined with idsubcat which is an auto-increment integer, to ensure a unique id number to each sub_category.

IF that INSERT was done ok, then insert in to the category table.  Again just the query:

```
INSERT INTO cat (category, sub_category) 
VALUES (:cat, 
        (SELECT idsubcat FROM subcat WHERE sub_category = :subCat)
       )
```

- So the second insert links the subcategory you just created.
- The preferred solution here is to setup a transaction.  Either both queries run, either both fail (and are rollback).  This prevents integrity problems.
- Your cat table should also define sub_category as a foreign key to the subcat table to ensure only valid values are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using PDO's [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), assuming ID in first table is an autoincrement field.

```
foreach ($xml -> m as $row){
    $cat = $row->category;
    $subCat = $row->sub_category;

    // TABLE 1 INSERT
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (category) VALUES (:cat)");
    $sql->bindValue('cat', $cat);
    $sql->execute();

    $catID = $con->lastInsertId();

    // TABLE 2 INSERT
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 (category, sub_category) VALUES (:cat_id, :subCat)");
    $sql->bindValue('cat_id', $catID);
    $sql->bindValue('subCat', $subCat);
    $sql->execute();

}
```